# localization in joomla and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, joomla

I want to write site like this http://kuss.hmsite.net/ but on CMS Joomla or Wordpress. So I need to implement login users, upload files on server, menu, registration, localization of all information on site (articles, titles while registering - all info). What CMS better to choose for these purposes? Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress have better performance and for me is easier in development. Look for the tutorials and figure out witch solution is better for You.

I recommend wordpress